# In tomcat log messages,is it possible to add file name in the log messages

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

Actually I am monitoring more than one Tomcat log files using Taillistener API in java.  Now I want to find that log messages are coming  from which tomcat.

Is it possible to add log file name in the log messages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of log4j instead of the standard `java.util.logging` Tomcat uses.

That will allow you to set a log file per Tomcat instance and much more.

See [Tomcat Log4J Logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By using log4j,is it possible to add file name in that log messages?.

Comment: Yes, you just need to change your appender pattern. Example: 
log4j.appender.CATALINA.conversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n. Have a look at http://www.laliluna.de/articles/log4j-tutorial.html